# How can I establish a TLS connection to a device with an untrusted certificate in my local network in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, ssl-certificate, remote-control

My task is to create a remote control for Android TV for iOS. After unsuccessful attempts to find any SDK that provides such an opportunity, I decided to rewrite [androidtv-remote](https://github.com/louis49/androidtv-remote). This library can do everything I need. To create a TLS connection, I decided to use the SocketIO. But my problem is that the TV has an untrusted certificate and the connection cannot happen.

```
let manager = SocketManager(
    socketURL: .init(string: "https://\(host):\(port)")!,
    config: [
        .sessionDelegate(self)
    ]
)

self.socketManager = manager
let socket = manager.defaultSocket

socket.onAny { event in
    print(event.event.uppercased())
}

socket.connect()


extension PairingManager: URLSessionDelegate {
    func urlSession(
        _ session: URLSession,
        didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge,
        completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?
        ) -> Void) {
        guard let serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust else {
            completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)

            return
        }

        completionHandler(.useCredential, .init(trust: serverTrust))
    }
}
```

1. Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://192.168.0.101:6467/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&EIO=4, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <324E645E-2EB5-4024-A361-AAC93D7895C2>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
   "LocalDataTask <324E645E-2EB5-4024-A361-AAC93D7895C2>.<1>
2. Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “192.168.0.101” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(
   "<cert(0x10500e400) s: atvremote/MTCMSD6886EU/bangbae/EU 4K Android TV/1C:30:08:93:4C:CD i: atvremote/MTCMSD6886EU/bangbae/EU 4K Android TV/1C:30:08:93:4C:CD>"
   ), NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://192.168.0.101:6467/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&EIO=4, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://192.168.0.101:6467/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&EIO=4, NSUnderlyingError=0x2827bd110 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1202 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x2818ec0a0>, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9807, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9807, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=(
   "<cert(0x10500e400) s: atvremote/MTCMSD6886EU/bangbae/EU 4K Android TV/1C:30:08:93:4C:CD i: atvremote/MTCMSD6886EU/bangbae/EU 4K Android TV/1C:30:08:93:4C:CD>"
   )}}, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
   "LocalDataTask <5CC821A4-3477-4201-8CBE-0E2BA018DF02>.<1>"
   ), _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9807, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <5CC821A4-3477-4201-8CBE-0E2BA018DF02>.<1>, NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x2818ec0a0>, NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “192.168.0.101” which could put your confidential information at risk.}
3. Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, NSUnderlyingError=0x2803512c0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<CFData 0x282e15f40 [0x2208eac08]>{length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x10021943c0a800650000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <49F62856-E6A2-4F2A-9A0F-B4FDA7473E3F>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
   "LocalDataTask <49F62856-E6A2-4F2A-9A0F-B4FDA7473E3F>.<1>"
   ), NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.0.101:6467/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&EIO=4, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.0.101:6467/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&EIO=4, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}

But as a result, I get different errors, depending on the configuration.

1. The first error I get is with the above code
2. The second error I get is if I don't do the processing in the URLSessionDelegate
3. The third error occurs if I establish a connection using the HTTP protocol and not HTTPS

Comment: you can not achieve this using SocketIO, you need to establish TLS connection using `NWConnection` of `Network` framework.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **URLSessionDelegate** to bypass the SSL validation, you can manually trust the certificate on the iOS device. Here's an example code:

```
func trustCertificateManually() {
let host = "host"
let port = "port"

guard let serverURL = URL(string: "https://\(host):\(port)") else {
    return
}

let serverTrust = serverURL.securityTrust()

if serverTrust != nil {
    // Save the serverTrust object for the duration of your app's session
    URLCredentialStorage.shared.setCredential(
        URLCredential(trust: serverTrust!),
        for: serverURL
    )
}

// Proceed with establishing the connection
let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: serverURL)
// your code...
   }

    extension URL {
    func securityTrust() -> SecTrust? {
     var trust: SecTrust?
     let policy = SecPolicyCreateSSL(true, self.host as CFString)
     let status = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(self as CFURL, policy, &trust)
    
    guard status == errSecSuccess else {
        return nil
    }
    
    return trust
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Network framework is have wrote [Samir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5973760/samir-bagaria).
`NWConnection` + `NWParameters` with `NWProtocolTLS.Options`